# Can't return the root node of TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get the root node of selected item in TreeView, for example, if I've:

```
Italy
     Serie A
```

and the user select `Serie A`, in the code was return Italy parent root.
So I've create this variable inside a method:

```
var country = FindRootNode(nation_team.SelectedItem);
```

and this is the method:

```
private TreeViewItem FindRootNode(TreeView treeNode)
{
    while (treeNode.Parent != null)
    {
        treeNode = (TreeView)treeNode.Parent;
    }
     return treeNode;
}
```

but I'm not sure if this code is correct, anyway, `return treeNode` is underlined in red, with this error:

> Can not implicitly convert type System.Windows.Controls.TreeView in System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `treeNode` which is a `TreeView` object to a `TreeViewItem` object.

With this line :

```
treeNode = (TreeView)treeNode.Parent;
```

Before using it make sure you are casting the SelectedItem to TreeViewItem like so :

```
FindRootNode(nation_team.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem)
```

What you are looking for is this recursive approach :

```
private TreeViewItem FindRootNode(TreeViewItem currentItem){

    if(currentItem == null) return null;
    var tvi = (TreeViewItem)currentItem.Parent;
    if(tvi == null){
      return currentItem;
    }
    else{
        return FindRootNode(tvi);
    }
}
```

Or this iterative one :

```
private TreeViewItem FindRootNode(TreeViewItem currentItem){
     if(currentItem == null) return null;
     while(currentItem.Parent as TreeViewItem!= null){
         currentItem = currentItem.Parent as TreeViewItem;
     }
     return currentItem;
}
```

Comment: currentItem = currentItem.Parent; CurrentItem.Parent is underlined in red, this is the error: Can not implicitly convert type System.Windows.DependencyObject in System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem

Comment: Thank you, I've one question: var country = FindRootNode(nation_team.SelectedItem);
is correct? Because the compiler tell me argument not valid.

Comment: You have to cast it to TreeViewItem like so  var country = FindRootNode(nation_team.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem)

Comment: Use debug mode and check the inner exception and then post it here , you can also inspect the method action to see if it ends

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88186/discussion-between-bender-and-chris).